# Show that $d(x,y)=\min \{1,|x-y|\}$ is a metric on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Is the following just a matter of showing the 3 properties that make up a metric??

Define d on $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ by $d(x,y)=\min \{1,|x-y|\}$. Show that $d$ is a metric on $\Bbb R$

1. $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$
2. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ for every $x,y \in X$
3. $d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$ for every $x,y,z \in X$

Comment: Yes. Note that for every metric $d'$ the construction $d(x,y)=\min\{1,d'(x,y)\}$ yields a metric.

Comment: Which of the three conditions are you having trouble showing?

Comment: well the triangle inequality always seems to be the more difficult one to show.

Comment: You're missing the property that $d(x,y)>0$ if $x\neq y$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's correct (though your first condition should read "if and only if $x=y$"). This is what is known sometimes as the *standard bounded metric* induced by the metric $\rho(x,y)=|x-y|$. More generally, if $\langle X,\rho\rangle$ is **any** metric space, then the function $$d(x,y)=\min\{1,\rho(x,y)\}$$ is again a metric on $X$, called the standard bounded metric induced by $\rho$, and induces the same metric topology.

To prove that it is in fact a metric, the first two properties are relatively straightforward. For the triangle inequality, note that if $\rho(x,y)\ge1$ or $\rho(y,z)\ge 1,$ then $$d(x,y)+d(y,z)\ge1\ge d(x,z).$$ Otherwise, we have $$d(x,y)+d(y,z)=\rho(x,y)+\rho(y,z)\ge\rho(x,z)\ge d(x,z)$$ by definition of $d,$ since $\rho$ is a metric.

Comment: It even induces the same uniform structure :-)

Comment: @StefanH : what's "uniform structure"?

Comment: @StefanSmith: It is a structure between metric and topology where you have a kind of neighborhoods which are uniform over the whole space, they are called entourages. So you can take an entourage $U$ and put it around a point $x$ to get the neighborhood $U(x)$, the same way as you can choose an $ϵ$ and then put the ball $B_ϵ$ around $x$ to get the neighborhood $B_ϵ(x)$ in a metric space. So a metric induces a uniform structure, and a uniform structure induces a topology.

Comment: @StefanSmith: My first comment may be understood as: *The identity map is uniformly continuous.* So it is not only continuous (preserves the topology) but uniformly continuous (preserves the uniform structure). It is, however, not an isometry, as it does not maintain the distances.