# Show that $\|x\| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}(\min\{|x_n|,1\})$ satisfies the triangle inequality

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $$\|x\| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}(\min\{|x_n|,1\})$$ where $x=(x_1,\dots) \in A$. And  $A$ is the vector space formed by $F(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R}).$ Show that $\|x\|$ satsifies the triangle inequality,

I'm trying to determine wheter this sum satisfies the triangle inequality, but the minimum function inside the sum is giving me hard time I have that $$\|x+y\| = 2^{-1}(\min\{|x_1+y_1|,1\}) + 2^{-2}(\min\{|x_2+y_2|,1\}) + \dots + 2^{-n}(\min\{|x_n+y_n|,1\})$$ but I'm not sure how to go further. How can I bound this?

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/533795/42969

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, note that the map $\eta(x)=\min\{|x|,1\}$  satisfies the triangle inequality. In fact,\begin{align}\eta(x+y)&=\min\{|x+y|,1\}\\&\leqslant\min\{|x|+|y|,1\}\\&\leqslant\min\{|x|,1\}+\min\{|y|,1\}.\end{align}But then $2^{-n}\eta$ also staisfies the triangle inequality. So, since your function is a sum of functions for which the triangle inequality holds, then it also holds for your function.